# System.NullReferenceException with datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to fill two arrays with the content of two columns of a Datagridview. I wrote this:

```
 Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        Dim t As Integer = (DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1)
        For i = 0 To t
            avx(i) = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("Av").Value
            hi(i) = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("h").Value
            avsum = Val(avsum + avx(i))
        Next
        Label2.Text = Val(avsum)
    End Sub
```

When I start debugging, I receive this error at the fourth line of the reported code.

```
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
```

Does someone know how to solve this issue? How could I initialise Datagridview1? It has been already initialised in Designer section so, if I try to initialise it again, I receive obviously a conflict.

Comment: You have already asked about this problem. What was not clear in the duplicate that explains what a nullreferenceexception is?

Comment: I didn't find anything about solving this issue. As I wrote, I tried to initialise Datagridview1 but with no success

Comment: The controls defined in the designer file are initialized by a call to the method InitializeComponent and this is done in the constructor of the form. Do you have this call in the form's constructor?

Comment: No, I don't have the command you mentioned. I tried to fill in the code before the second line ('Dim t as integer...') but I'm receiving the same error, so I think this isn't the right way to use it

Comment: _Public Sub New() InitializeComponent() End Sub_ but this should be done only if you need to create the default constructor yourself otherwise the call is made automatically

Comment: I added what you wrote me before the private sub for the button I reported in the answer but I'm having back the same error. Isn't this the right way to add this command?

Comment: It's not about initialization, you have this code on a Button.Click handler, the DGV has been initialized already. Do you have a NewRow in that DGV? You should check for null before tying to use a Cell value. -- Also, why do you have an array there? How did you initialize that? To what upper bound? It looks like you're using those values in-place, just to set the text of a Label -- What's `hi(i) = ` for? You never use it.

Comment: I'm filling that DGV and I have to obtain the sum of the column. Could you explain what do you mean with "check for null before tying to use a Cell value"? I'm sorry if it seems a stupid question but I'm still a newbie with VB. Btw, I'm using arrays because at the end I have to plot a scatter graph with the values in the avx and hi values and I didn't write hi expression yet, here is why I'm still not using it.

Comment: All right, 1. Do you have a `NewRow` object in that DGV (the Row at the Bottom where you can insert new data)? If you do, your loop goes up to `Dim t As Integer = DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 2` 2. You should set Option Strict On (to avoid type mismatches that compromise the whole thing. This `Label2.Text = Val(avsum)` doesn't throw because of this. Maybe you think it's *helping*; it's not. At all) and check those Cells' content for null before using the value 3. Put a breakpoint in the first line of the loop, execute step by step and check all objects, see what is null, then you'll know why.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. 1. I tried before to see if the counter "t" worked properly through the text label 2 and it works fine: if, for example, i filled two rows, label2 was  equal to 2. 2. In VB Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB defaults -> Option Strict I set it to on. 3. I tried to obtain the single value of avx, so I deleted the loop and I tried to write it a single line but I'm having as value 0: avx = DataGridView1.Rows(1).Cells("Av").Value

Comment: Please stop using Val(). That is a left over from vb6 and is around only for backward compatibility. In new code use CInt, CDec etc.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my test, I can not reproduce your problem.

However, I make a sample code that may be similar to your question.

Form_Load event

```
 Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim table As New DataTable
        table = New DataTable()
        table.Columns.Add("Av")
        table.Columns.Add("h")
        table.Rows.Add("test1", "1001")
        table.Rows.Add("test2", "1002")
        table.Rows.Add("test3", "1003")
        DataGridView1.DataSource = table
        DataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = False

    End Sub
```

**Note: The AllowUserToAddRows property will reduce an extra row.**

Button_Click event:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim t As Integer = (DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1)
        Dim array1(t) As String
        Dim array2(t) As String
        For i = 0 To t
            array1(i) = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("Av").Value
            array2(i) = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("h").Value
        Next
        For index = 0 To t
            RichTextBox1.AppendText(array1(index) + Environment.NewLine)
            RichTextBox2.AppendText(array2(index) + Environment.NewLine)
        Next
    End Sub
```

Final result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks all for your answers. avx and hi are two arrays that are built compiling that datagridview through adding lines. The size of arrays, then, isn't fixed but it's variable on the Number of rows are filled in the DGV by the user. For this reason I think I can't set AllowUserToAddRows on false.

Comment: @Nicola, if the size if arrays is not fixed, I suggest that you can use List to replace the array. Besides, the AllowUserToAddRows property only will delete the last blank row, it will not affect other rows.

Comment: J Jun thanks again for commenting. I can't set AllowUserToAddRows to False because I have to put data manually in my DGV and with this entry I'm no more able to fill it. Btw, about what you suggested me, I tried to use List(Of Double) from the DGV row and it seems to work. I'm having an issue about summing the content of the list. I wrote it as: avsum = Val(avsum + avx(i)) but it seems to go out of range

Comment: EDIT: I was filling the list in the wrong mode. Before I inizialised the list and then, through a for loop, I added values in it and now it's working properly. Thanks a lot for helping me!

Answer (score 0):

Can you describe about variable avx() and hi()
This error occur maybe datagridview row count greater than Array bound